# Metamask is showing "invalid amount" in metamask mobile app during transfer with etherjs but works fine in web plugin

Tags: metamask, decentralized-applications

I am getting an invalid amount error while connecting to my dapp using the metamask mobile appilication. It works fine with the browser plugin but not on the mobile app. I am trying to transfer BUSD using etherJs. I already connected with the BUSD contract and abi, and like I mentioned it works fine on web but shows "invalid amount" on mobile app. I'd really appreciate the help.

Here's what my code looks like

```
             const price_r = ethers.utils.parseUnits(price_, 18);
              const {BUSDContract, signer} = await getContract();  
              const contract = BUSDContract.connect(signer)
              m_response = await contract.transfer(
                '0xf0e2fb4174A66dbD5A4B94B9D6331eA05460542d',
                `${amount}`,
                {
                  gasLimit: 3000000,
                }
              );
```

This works quite when with the metamask browser plugin. However, when I switch to the metamask mobile app it shows the invalid amount as shown below.

[Metamask mobile invalid error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb428.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add gasLimit and gasPrice:

```
const gasLimit = await Contract.estimateGas.transfer(to, amount, {from: account });
const gasPrice = await library.getGasPrice();
    
const tx = await Contract.transfer(to, amount, {
  from: account,
  gasLimit: gasLimit,
  gasPrice: gasPrice
});
const response = await tx.wait();
return response;
```

Comment: This is similar to what I currently have. However, this doesn't seem to work. Still have the invalid amount showing

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes into this issue, I was able to resolve it by switching from etherjs to web3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).